# Getting a debug assertion of "Expression: can't dereference value-initialized vector iterator"

Tags: c++, path-finding

I am trying to create A* pathfinding algorithm and model it with OpenGL. However, in the algorithm part, I get the error:"Expression: can't dereference value-initialized vector iterator". I think I've limited it to this block of code here yet I don't understand why this error happens. This block of code comes from a function that takes an sNode start and end (start being the beginning of the path and end being the goal) by reference and then stores start in openList. In the while loop, I try to find the value with the lowest fCost in the openList and then erase whatever that value may be from the list.

```
        std::vector<sNode> openList;
        openList.emplace_back(start);

        bool destinationFound = false;

        while (!openList.empty() && openList.size() < (boardHeight * boardWidth)) {
            sNode node;

            do {
                float temp = FLT_MAX;
                std::vector<sNode>::iterator itNode;

                for (std::vector<sNode>::iterator it = openList.begin(); it != openList.end(); it = next(it)) {
                    sNode n = *it;
                    if (n.fCost < temp) {
                        temp = n.fCost;
                      //itNode now equals this new value
                        itNode = it;
                    }
                }

                node = *itNode;
                openList.erase(itNode);
            } while (isValid(node, node.pos.first, node.pos.second) == false);
```

Here is the struct I made for sNode as well:

```
struct sNode
{
    bool Walkable = true;
    bool isStart = false;
    bool isGoal = false;
    bool isPath = false;
    bool traveledTo = false;

    int gCost;
    int hCost;
    int fCost;
    std::pair<int, int> Parent;

    int type = 0;

    std::pair<int, int> pos;

    sNode() {
        gCost = 0;
        hCost = 0;
        fCost = 0;
    }

    bool operator==(const sNode& node) {
        if (this->pos == node.pos)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: note the existence of [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element). And you should either follow the rule of three/five, or (better in your case) the rule of zero. Learn to use [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization). And [`auto` is your friend](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/)

Comment: Also, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Presumably nothing matches your condition or `openList` is empty resulting in nothing being assigned to `itNode`. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Get rid of the unnecessary user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator for `sNode`.  That extra code does nothing except slow the program down and leave you open for bugs if you happen to forget a member.  The compiler default version will work just fine, with no errors.

Comment: Whenever I run the function I store the start node that is passed by reference into the openList, so I'm still a little confused. Also, sorry, I am new to StackOverflow and programming as a whole.

Comment: `std::vector<sNode>::iterator itNode;` -- This isn't initialized to anything, and there is no guarantee it has a value when you get to `node = *itNode;`.  If your goal is to erase a certain item in the vector, use `std::find_if` instead of writing a loop to search.  Or maybe you are trying to find the smallest item?  If so, there is `std::min_element` -- no need for a `for` loop.

Comment: That entire `float temp = FLT_MAX;` `for` loop, and `erase` could be replaced with two lines of code: `auto iter = std::min_element(openList.begin(); openList.end(), [](auto& s1, auto& s2) { return s1.fCost < s2.fCost; }); openList.erase(iter);`.  Whether this is the problem, I don't know since a [mcve] wasn't posted.  But that message comes from Visual C++.  You should have been using the debugger and look at the call stack to see exactly which line is giving the assertion error.